# How to set associative array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to send some data to server.

I have some maping by specify elements and i want to send a result.

```
var slectVal = {};
selectVal = $.map(filterValueArray, function(el) {
    return (
        el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-filter-name') + ":" + el.value
    )
});

var data = {
    "filters" : selectVal
}

$.post(url, data).done(function(res){
    var postStatus = res.status;
});
```

Everyting is ok but what is sending to server is:

```
filters[]:Name:SomeName
filters[]:City:SomeCity
```

How to send it as a associative array, like this:

```
filters[Name]:SomeName
filters[City]:SomeCity
```

Comment: `$.map()` always returns an array. You want (and have declared) an *object*. adeneo's answer is on target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the structure of the data

```
var data = {filters: {}};

$.each(filterValueArray, function(_, el) {
    data.filters[$(el).parent().data('filter-name')] = el.value;
});

$.post(url, data).done(function(res){
    var postStatus = res.status;
});
```

Comment: I have this error: `Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined`

Comment: That's my bad, I forgot an `s` in `filters`, I'll edit it now.